# DNSClient is Not able to ping DNSserver by its hostname BUT able to ping by its IP

Tags: linux, dns

I have Two Linux Machine Redhat & Centos Under Window 7(as host) In Vmware Workstation.
I configure DNS server & DHCP Server in Redhat(10.0.0.1).

Client which is Centos is able to get IP(10.0.0.30) from DHCP server but it is not picking up name from DNS Server.

```
Problem is At server 10.0.0.1 i am able to ping itself by hostname like 
root@server->ping server.example.com       Ping successfull

But Client is not able to ping Server by Hostname like
root@localhost->ping server.example.com   Ping Not Successfull

Client is able to ping Server by its ip like
root@localhost->ping 10.0.0.1             Ping Successfull
```

**Now My questn is that Why Client is not able to ping server by its hostname & why client is not picking up name from DNS server,**

Comment: Try `nslookup server.example.com`. Likely the IP is not resolving.

Comment: NO sir.Client is not able to do nslookup server.example.com.If i run this command on server then no problem but on client not resolving                                            [root@localhost ~]# nslookup server.example.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: is the DHCP server providing the DNS Server address???

Comment: Then it looks like you don't have a working DNS server available to the client.

Comment: HOw to check it. Can you confirm it sir.Now one problem is resolved,client is able to pick hostname from DNS server.But client is not able to ping server by its hostname.Or if i do nslookup on client it is not resolving query.BUt when i do nslookup on server it is able to resolve

Answer (score 2):

Just had similar issue on my Debian VM running on a Win7 host.

Setting up DNS server isn't enough to resolve server name, especially when proxy is used in your network environment.
To solve it, you've to export http_proxy environment variable on command line before calling other executables. For example:

```
export http_proxy="http://{your proxy ip address here}:{your proxy port here}"
```

As usual, remember to add it to your profile script so you don't redo it after each boot.